# Dynamics mapping

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales

I have  a requirement, Entity A -> I have a lookup field through which i can create New Record for three other entities. When I search Test in lookup field and click New Record, it opens a quick create form and I enter the details and save the record. The issue is, whatever i enter in lookup field it should show in first name field og the quick create form. I know i need to do data mapping. I tried it didnt work. Also I couldnt see the Mapping Tab in the Solution Explorer.

How could i achieve this???

Comment: Mapping will be in that particular lookup Relationship..

Comment: No there is no relationship . I checked with Microsoft. they say its been hardcoded, but not with any code. No idea what. waiting for them to reply back and say where its been hardcoded

Comment: I understand its a default dynamics behaviour that when i search and get opened the quick create form. the searched data is getting pre populated in lastname field, where the lastname cannot be empty so the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand its a default dynamics behaviour that when i search and get opened the quick create form. the searched data is getting pre populated in lastname field, where the lastname cannot be empty so the reason.